# jsPDF se descuadra al poner .fromHTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf

Estoy utilizando jsPDF para generar html. Estoy utilizando la siguiente función:

```
      jsPDF.fromHTML(numOperacion++ + ' : ' + texto, 20, 80 + (c * 48));
```

Y me descuadra todo, así es como sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando esta siguiente me saldría bien, pero necesito que sea .fromHTML

```
  doc.text(numOperacion++ + ' : ' + texto, 20, 80 + (c * 48));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sí alguien sabe lo que pasa sería de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución. Simplemente, tenía que poner un nuevo parámetro y asignarle el width a ese:

```
doc.fromHTML(numOperacion++ + ' : ' + texto, 20, 80 + (c * 48), {
    'width': 130
});
```